# Issues setting a value to a select box on the onload

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm having issues setting a value to a select box when loading the page.
On the onload I parse the URL for variables and after that I have to set the values retrieved from the url to a specific select box.
The problem is when I'm trying to set the value using dijit:

```
dijit.byId("assettypeselect").set('value',queryObject.assettypeselect);
```

an error occurs because dijit library is not loaded yet.
I've used dojo.addOnLoad and dojo.ready, but none of those work. Is there another eventhandler I can use that waits until all libraries are loaded or in what other way can I work to solve this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely solution, based off the limited information you've provided, is to wait for the `window`'s `load` event to fire. If `dijit` is still `undefined` have a look in your console and check to make sure the external/internal library is being requested properly. Also, if `dijit` is being loaded AMD style, make sure you've [referenced it as a dependency](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/info.html#dijit-basics).

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    dijit.byId("assettypeselect").set('value',queryObject.assettypeselect);
}, false);
```

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload#Notes

Comment: It was a great help. I really apreciate it! I turned out I had to make sure I declared the selct box with data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select"